# Google map to display multiple locations in Django Project

Tags: django, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I want to use Google map to show more than one mail address in my django project. The addresses are variables from the database.

Till now, I have tried `django-easy-maps` which is great for showing only ONE address. Like it said it is very easy to use if you have only one address (may be able to show more than one).

I also tried `django-gmapi` which can show more than one address (in latlng format). But I have a hard time to convert my us  post address to latlng format.

So my questions are:

1. Does `django-easy-maps` support more than one address?
2. How to use `geocoding` with `django-gmapi`
3. Any suggestions how to show more than one us post address on Google map in Django?

Answer (score 0):

I can maybe help address point 2 ...how to geocode your existing addresses.

**UPDATE**
It looks like gmapi has it's own geocoding helper built in so you probably don't need any of the code I pasted below. See: [Does anybody has experiences with geocoding using django-gmapi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143755/does-anybody-has-experiences-with-geocoding-using-django-gmapi)

---

I have used the following code:

```
import urllib

from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.encoding import smart_str
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.utils import simplejson as json


def get_lat_long(location):
    output = "csv"
    location = urllib.quote_plus(smart_str(location))
    request = "http://maps.google.co.uk/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%s&sensor=false" % location
    response = urllib.urlopen(request).read()
    data = json.loads(response)
    if data['status'] == 'OK':
        # take first result
        return (str(data['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']), str(data['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']))
    else:
        return (None, None)

def get_geocode(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    tlat, tlon = instance._geocode__target_fields
    if not getattr(instance, tlat) or not getattr(instance, tlon):
        map_query = getattr(instance, instance._geocode__src_field, '')
        if callable(map_query):
            map_query = map_query()
        lat, lon = get_lat_long(map_query)
        setattr(instance, tlat, lat)
        setattr(instance, tlon, lon)

def geocode(model, src_field, target_fields=('lat','lon')):
    # pass src and target field names as strings
    setattr(model, '_geocode__src_field', src_field)
    setattr(model, '_geocode__target_fields', target_fields)
    pre_save.connect(get_geocode, sender=model)
```

(Possibly I borrowed it from a Github project somewhere, I have lost the attribution if so, sorry!)

Then on your model you need something like:

```
from django.db import models
from gmaps import geocode # import the function from above

class MyModel(models.Model):
    address = models.TextField(blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True)

    lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=6, verbose_name='latitude', blank=True, null=True, help_text="Will be filled automatically.")
    lon = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=6, verbose_name='longitude', blank=True, null=True, help_text="Will be filled automatically.")

    def map_query(self):
        """
        Called on save by the geocode decorator which automatically fills the
        lat,lng values. This method returns a string to use as query to gmaps.
        """
        map_query = ''
        if self.address and self.city:
            map_query = '%s, %s' % (self.address, self.city)
        if self.postcode:
            if map_query:
                map_query = '%s, ' % map_query
            map_query = '%s%s' % (map_query, self.postcode)
        return map_query

geocode(Venue, 'map_query')
```

Then to geocode your existing data you could just re-save all the existing records, eg:

```
from .models import MyModel

for obj in MyModel.objects.all():
    obj.save()
```

Comment: @user1046012 oh, I see that other question was yours too so I guess you have the answer already!